# Angular: How to test RadioButton?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

Angular Material offers MatButtonHarness to test regular HTML buttons. With it you can 'getText', 'click'.

Is there something similar to test RadioButtons? I'd expect MatRadioHarness to exist, but it does not.

If not, what would be a recommended approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any documentation, but looking where is the source code for "MatButtonHarness" (~myproject\node_modules@angular\material\button) I was able to identify location with harness classes for radio buttons (c:\Project\AngularLearning\Frontend\node_modules@angular\material\radio).

In the 'testing' subfolder I was able to find actual classes to work with Radio Button Harness: MatRadioGroupHarness and MatRadioButtonHarness. Obvious answers but what was confusing is that the class for the radio button does not have 'button' in it.

After I found specific classes I googled for those and identified the working example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rllllvapblod?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-harness-example.spec.ts

And an important part to make it work was to add MatRadioModule to import section for my test initialization:

```
describe('MapsComponent', () => {
  let component: MapsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MapsComponent>;
  let componentService: HexesService;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [MatRadioModule],
        declarations: [MapsComponent],
      }).compileComponents();
    ...
```

Hope this will help someone as well!